# как проверить статус участника (админ, создатель, участник) канала в библиотеке aiogram v3

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть список каналов с айдишниками. Я хочу пройтись по этому списку и узнать есть ли в администраторах канала тот пользователь который использует бота. Как мне это можно сделать ?, изучил документацию aiogram полностью и не передать словами моего разочарования в ней.

Единственное что я там понял так это: "так это то что где то можно использовать get_chat_member там гдето есть что типо aiogram.get_chat_administrator.ADMINISTRATO что то там вот там вот так вот потом так потом ADMISITRATOR потом там вот CREATOR" Совершенно не понимаю как мне это можно сделать.

Обрыл весь гугл, ну просто немогу найти ответ. Где то версия библиотеки не та, где то функции нет. Я не понмаю как этим пользоваться помомгите мне!

Answer (score 0):

В общем я решил это! Наконец то это получилось, если кто не понял что я хотел зделать так вот код:

```
> channels_admin = list()
> 
> for id_channel in CHANELS_IN_MODERATION:
> 
>     user_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id= id_channel, user_id= message.from_user.id)
> 
>     if isinstance(user_status, ChatMemberAdministrator):
>         channels_admin.append(f'{id_channel}')
>     else:
>         pass
```

я мне в сумме надо было узнать в каких каналах является админом юзер и это у меня наконец то получилось!!!